# delete a file from local drive after successful upload to ftp using batch file

Tags: batch-file, window, scheduling

i want to delete file from my local system after successful send to ftp using batch file. for scheduling purpose i m using window scheduler. below is my code which is able to post to ftp.how to delete that successful send to ftp otherwise file shld not delete.

```
 %windir%\system32\ftp.exe -s:%~f0
 goto done
 cd C:\
 open Host Name
 user_name
 password
 bi
 put user_input.csv
 bye
 :done
 @echo off
 cls
 exit
```

if i will write delete here then it ll delete from remote server.pls suggest me how to do that using window ftp.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redirect the output of the FTP command. Check for a succesful message and act upon it.

I can't provide an exact script, because it will depend on the FTP command you actually use, but the idea is like this.

```
echo open Host Name >%temp%\ftpin.txt
echo user_name >>%temp%\ftpin.txt
echo password >>%temp%\ftpin.txt
echo put user_input.csv >>%temp%\ftpin.txt
echo bye  >>%temp%\ftpin.txt
ftp -n -s:%temp%\ftpin.txt >%temp%\ftpout.txt
for /f "tokens=* skip=9" %%a in (ftpout.txt) do (
   if "%%a"=="226 Transfer complete." (
   del user_input.csv
   )
)
```

**EDIT**: You will have to adjust your BAT to the actual output of your FTP script. Probably you will need to change the `"skip"` parameter of the `FOR` command.

Comment: thanks PA for reply.i tried whatever you told but its not uploading the file also.i dnt know where i am doing wrong.its wrote till bye in ftpin.txt. echo open xxx.xxx.xxx.xx >%temp%\ftpin.txt
echo Fusion-HCM >>%temp%\ftpin.txt
echo ora8945$ >>%temp%\ftpin.txt
echo put J:\Users\ADITYARAJ SINGH\profile.xml >>%temp%\ftpin.txt
echo bye  >>%temp%\ftpin.txt
ftp -n -s:%temp%\ftpin.txt >%temp%\ftpout.txt
for /f "tokens=* skip=9" %%a in (ftpout.txt) do (
   if "%%a"=="226 Transfer complete." (
   del J:\Users\ADITYARAJ SINGH\profile.xml
   )
)

Comment: First, if the file is not uploading, then you have to review your script. It has nothing to do with the check of the output. Maybe the blank in the filename???  Second, see my recent update of the answer.