# Windows Batch Delete Local file after upload

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a windows batch script that cycles through all files in a folder and uploads to ftp and then deletes the local file. This works great when there are no spaces in the file name:

```
@for %%f in (D:\local\file\path\nospaces\*.jpg) do (
  @echo cd  /remote/file/path/nospaces/ && @echo put %%f && @echo !del %%f
)>> %SCRIPT_NAME%
```

When spaces are introduced, I am able to get the file to upload by using quotes around the path, but the local will not delete:

```
@for %%f in ("D:\local directory with spaces\*.jpg") do (
  @echo cd "/remote directory with spaces/" && @echo put "%%f" && @echo !del "%%f"
)>> %SCRIPT_NAME%
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: I should also state the error I'm getting:
"The system cannot find the specified file"

Comment: You may check result of ftp.exe and delete it by next line in a loop like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18579970/5920627

Comment: In your second example, try with `"%%~f"` rather than `"%%f"` (twice)...

Answer (score 0):

```
@for %%f in ("D:\local directory with spaces\*.jpg") do (
  @echo cd "/remote directory with spaces/" && @echo put "%%f" && @echo !echo "%%f">log.txt
)>> %SCRIPT_NAME%

ftp.exe -s:%SCRIPT_NAME%

for /f "delims=" %%f in (log.txt) do del /q "%%f"

del /q log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where I ended up:

@for %%f in ("D:\local directory with spaces*.jpg") do (
  @echo cd "/remote directory with spaces/" && @echo put "%%f" && @echo %%f>>log.txt)>> %SCRIPT_NAME%

@echo quit>> %SCRIPT_NAME%

@REM = Now call FTP with our generated script
@ftp -s:%SCRIPT_NAME%

@REM = Delete our temp script file and we are done
@del %SCRIPT_NAME% /q

for /f "delims=" %%f in (log.txt) do del /q "%%f"

del /q log.txt